# Can I create new page.php on child theme in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to create new page (with specific style) on child theme. I created a page.php on child theme, however, it doesn't work. Instead of, parent theme's pape.php does.
When I remove the parent theme's pape.php, it redirects index.php.

Can I create new page.php on child theme in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange. As i understood you can overload all the files in your parent-theme from the child-theme by just creating a new -filename-.php. Here is som good reading [Wordpress Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)