# Child theme is only using index.php and not inheriting templates from parent theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme that I've developed and want to make child themes. My `wp-content/themes` directory looks something like this:

```
parenttheme
    |- style.css
    |- functions.php
    |- index.php
    |- page-example.php
childtheme
    |- style.css
    |- functions.php
    |- index.php
```

The problem is that `page-example.php` doesn't load in a site using `childtheme`, only `childtheme/index.php` is used.

I can do something like this in `childtheme/index.php`:

```
echo body_class(); // class="page page-id-24 page-template page-template-page-example page-template-page-example-php logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support"
```

The correct looking classes are there (`page-template-page-example`), but it's not using the parenttheme template file.

My hacky solution so far is to add a `childtheme/page-example.php` file that just contains a `require('parenttheme/page-example.php')`, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do that.

I found this post, which seems to be my exact problem, but there was no answer... [Can I create new page.php on child theme in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141514/can-i-create-new-page-php-on-child-theme-in-wordpress)

I've read through the WordPress child theme codex and exhausted all other resources I can think of on the topic. Is there anyone who has dealt with this problem before?

I'm using WordPress 4.4 and multisites, if that matters.

The full template in question:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Membership
*/

get_header();

?>

<div class="site-bd">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hero">
            <?php
                if (have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) :
                        the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="shelf shelf_3">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <?php
                if( have_rows('top_columns') ) :
                    while ( have_rows('top_columns') ) : the_row();
            ?>
            <div class="grid_item grid_item-oneThird">
                <div class="shelf">
                    <div class="shelf">
                        <?php the_sub_field('column_1'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="vList">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn" target="_blank">Join or Renew Online</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn" target="_blank">Download Membership Form</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><div class="grid_item grid_item-oneThird">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="shelf">
                        <?php the_sub_field('column_2'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="grid_item grid_item-oneThird">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="shelf">
                        <?php the_sub_field('column_3'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've got a dozen or so other templates that also don't work though.

Comment: Can you add the content of the template file to your question?

Comment: @JamesJones, I've added the template that I'm trying to get working, there are a few others that all behave as described in the original post though

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that template. I reckon your parent theme isn't being activated. In your admin themes page can you look at your child theme which is currently activated and look out for this text? `This is a child theme of 'parenttheme'` .

Comment: @JamesJones yeah, I'm using multisite, if that matters. So, if I go to My Sites > Network Admin > Themes > Edit (under the child theme) then I do see `This child theme inherits templates from a parent theme, Student Press.` "Student Press" is the parent name. However, I don't see anything listing them as child themes anywhere else, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with multisite, however you can test by creating `page-example.php` in your child theme and see if it works

Comment: scratch last comment I can see you've already checked that

Comment: I'm a bit stumped, I'll post a few tips to diagnose but don't have a solution

Answer (score 3):

This is the message I was talking about in the comments. This is shown on the themes page of a child theme: [image]

If not you may not have your child theme setup correctly. Make sure your child theme `style.css` file has something like this at the top:

```
/*
Theme Name:         Boston
Theme URI:          http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au
Description:        Responsive Boston template child
Version:            1.0
Author:             James Jones
Author URI:         http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au
Template:           boston
Tags:               modern, two-columns, threaded-comments, custom-menu, translation-ready
*/
```

with the important part for child themes being the 'Template' entry.

**Other things you can try:**

In `wp-includes\template.php` check out the functions `load_template()` and `locate_template()`. Use `print_r()` to output what these functions are doing on page load to try and help you diagnose what files are being loaded and where it's going wrong.

Output the function `get_page_template()` in your `functions.php` to see what WordPress thinks it's outputting. This may also help you diangose.

Good luck or hope someone else comes along to shed more light.